# How to keep the VNC service running after reboot (RHEL 6)?

Tags: linux, rhel

I have installed the `vncserver` related package and am able to access the desktop through the client. But on restarting the Linux machine, I am loosing the VNC session and again I am supposed to run the vncserver command to enable the vnc session.

How can I permanently enable the VNC session, even after the rebooting of the Linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the service starts at boot.  To do this, run the following:

```
# chkconfig vncserver on
```

Note that this will start the service on the *next* boot.  To start it now, you will still need to run:

```
# service vncserver start
```

Comment: Sorry Peterph, I could have definetely done it but I don't have enough reputations to upvote. But as per your suggestion, I would definetely follow the habbit and ensure it.